# Entering Parameters into the Web Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a web report viewer which reports just fine. I have all the code for entering parameters etc. but the control UI itself doesn't seem to accommodate parameter input (i.e. textboxes/textfields etc). Is there anything I can use in the built-in control set or do I have to create my own?

Answer (score 0):

The SSRS report viewer control has a `ShowParameterPrompts` property.

```
ShowParameterPrompts="true"
```

Is this what you're looking for?